# Meteor Shell, can't import files from any folder: Error: Cannot find module ‘/imports/api/donuts/collection.js’

Tags: node.js, shell, meteor, import, es6-modules

I am having some trouble importing modules into the meteor shell.

Simple example:

1.create new project (meteor create myproject)

2.create file /imports/api/donuts/collection.js and paste content:

```
 // file: /imports/api/donuts/collection.js
 import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
 const Donuts = new Mongo.Collection('donuts');
 export default Donuts;
```

3.Run meteor shell and import the file by:

```
import Donuts from '/imports/api/donuts/collection.js'
```

than this error hits up:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/imports/api/donuts/collection.js'
at Function.require.resolve (packages/modules-runtime.js:129:19)
at Module.resolve (packages/modules-runtime.js:81:25)
at Module.Mp.import (/home/ec2-user/.meteor/packages/modules/.0.7.7.mccaq7++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/reify/lib/runtime.js:61:29)
at repl:1:-37
at packages/shell-server/shell-server.js:458:25
at /home/ec2-user/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.8.8.i94065++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/fiber_pool.js:32:39
```

What's wrong? File permissions are ok, I start the meteor shell from project root.

Thanks!

Comment: What Meteor version are you using?

Comment: I use Meteor 1.4.2, the instructions come form [Meteor Tuts](http://www.meteor-tuts.com/chapters/1/collections.html), interestingly if I create a test.js file in the root, it gets imported, but as I move it into a folder (client, import, etc..) it will not find it

Comment: It is most likely because it was not imported anywhere so it is not bundled in the app.

Comment: so I need to import it into say /server/main.js to make it available for the shell? But then why does the test.js file gets imported from the root while it is not included in anywhere? confused...

Comment: Files that are not inside an `imports` folder are eagerly loaded.

Comment: aaahaa, thanks!! I understand it now. Could you please add this last comment as an answer plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor originally loaded all of the source files using its [default load order](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#load-order).

In more recent versions (circa v1.3), it treats [special directories](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories) differently. One of those directories is **imports**.

> Any directory named `imports/` is not loaded anywhere and files must be imported using `import`.
>
> (from the Meteor docs)

When using the shell, you can only import resources that were included in the build. If the module (file) you are trying to import is not included in your import tree (chain of `import`s starting somewhere outside of the `/imports` directory), it will not be available for import.